# Using EXEC to create stored procedure to run update string column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, exec, execute

I have the following modification of my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTMSA_Test_Run] 
    @TableName nvarchar(200) = 'MyTable',
    @Parent int = 1145, 
    @Name nvarchar(100) = '''Test''',
    @KPI nvarchar(max) = '''Test''',
    @IDCount int = 1137
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC('UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET Parent = ' + @Parent + ', Name = ' + @Name  + ' , KPI = ' + @KPI + ' WHERE IDCount = ' + @IDCount) 
END
```

This procedure is executed successfully if I gave ''' before and after the string value. In case I left ' before and after the string value it will cause error.

Please help me find the reason why and solution as well. Thanks

Comment: Since your query is dynamic and you are concatenating a string to it. Sql will identify it is a string when ever you enclose it in  '''

Answer (score 1):

This procedure is an open door for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
Unless you have a really good reason why you need it to create dynamic SQL, I would suggest avoiding it.

If you can't avoid using dynamic sql, the least you can do is to use [`quotename`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to keep your procedure a little safer.

As to the problem you state in your question - just move the `'''` to the query body:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTMSA_Test_Run] 
    @TableName nvarchar(200) = 'MyTable',
    @Parent int = 1145, 
    @Name nvarchar(100) = 'Test',
    @KPI nvarchar(max) = 'Test',
    @IDCount int = 1137
AS
BEGIN

    EXEC('UPDATE QUOTENAME(' + @TableName + ') 
          SET Parent = ' + @Parent + ', 
              Name = ''' + @Name  + ''' , 
              KPI = ''' + @KPI + ''' 
          WHERE IDCount = ' + @IDCount)  
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTMSA_Test_Run] 
    @TableName nvarchar(200) = 'MyTable',
    @Parent int = 1145, 
    @Name nvarchar(100) = '''Test''',
    @KPI nvarchar(max) = '''Test''',
    @IDCount int = 1137
AS
BEGIN

　　declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
　　set @sql='UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET Parent = ' + @Parent + ', Name = ' + @Name  + ' , KPI = ' + @KPI + ' WHERE IDCount = ' + @IDCount
　　print @sql --find reason in the sql statement
    EXEC(@sql) 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `sp_executesql` and CAST `int` to `nvarchar` before executing query and QUOTENAME the `@tablename`.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTMSA_Test_Run] 
    @TableName nvarchar(200),
    @Parent int, 
    @Name nvarchar(100),
    @KPI nvarchar(max),
    @IDCount int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

    SELECT @sql = '
        UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' 
        SET Parent = ' + CAST(@Parent  as nvarchar(10))+ ', 
            Name = ''' + @Name  + ''', 
            KPI = ''' + @KPI + ''' 
        WHERE IDCount = ' + CAST(@IDCount as nvarchar(10)) + ';'


    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END
```